# align divs horrizontaly - the first one take all the horizontal available space

Tags: css, html, width, alignment

I have 2 divs which I need to arrange horizontally, I know the width of the second one and I need the first one to take all the remaining free space. can anyone help me and tell me the css in order to achieve that?

Comment: There are different ways to achieve that and depends very much on your design. It can be floated and a margin-right, or you can go over the positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<div style="width:500px;">
    <div style="width:100px;float:right;background-color:cyan;">bar</div>
    <div style="margin-right:100px;background-color:magenta">foo</div>
</div>
```

bar floats in the right 100px, on top of foo's margin.  foo takes the other 400px.

Comment: Even though my answer could be workable, I believe that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do something like that:

```
<div style="width:200px; float:left;"></div>
<div style="width:auto;"></div>
```

Comment: not really working, the first one should be auto and the second with fixed width to float right...but even like this, the second one will go under

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the width of the second container to your known value and the first one's to `width:100%;`

Comment: like this, the first one will take all the available space and the second one will go under

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentages, which is handy when you don't care about exact width. If you need an exact width, use javascript to get the offsetwidth of the div you KNOW, and floating both divs. Then, set the width of the other div accordingly. What I would caution against is setting the other div's value in pixels- if the user resizes the window you have to account for it which is more work. If you don't need it to be perfectly exact, set the other div as a percentage, which will automatically handle window resizing. 
Other issues crop up around it but basically thats one way of achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a little tricky.  But this should work...

http://jsfiddle.net/2hseV/2/

What this does is use div positioning.  This should be cross-browser compatible.  The reason I'm doing things this way is that there is no easy way to say "have two sibling divs, one of which consumes all available space" without pushing the second div off to the right.

For example, if you try using a percentage you'll either push the div to the right or come up short:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="width: 90px; height: 100%; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

So instead, I'm suggesting that you overlap the second div onto the first one using absolute positiong, like this:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; position: relative;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; float: left; position: relative;"><!-- Content of first div here --></div>
  <div style="width: 90px; height: 100%; float: left; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;"><!-- Content of second div here --></div>
</div>
```

The one thing you have to keep in mind here is that **the content of your first div will go under the second div if it becomes too wide - so you may need to restrict the width!**

Comment: well, works almost perfect, the problem is the second div height is larger then the first one and with absolute position the parent won't increase its height